# AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo is null when context menu is created in View's onCreateContextMenu

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have an application which has many views on fragments on an activity. Many of these views need context menus, so I had to define the context menus in the view's `onCreateContextMenu` instead of in the activity's `onCreateContextMenu`. The problem comes when I try to access the `AdapterContextMenuInfo` object as in

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

in the `onContextItemSelected` method of the activity..that object (info) returns null. How do I get this object in this situation? thanks.
In the View class, I have:
In its constructor, I initialize the listview from its view and register it
for the context menu:

```
class ContactsList  extends RelativeLayout implements OnItemClickListener,OnItemLongClickListener
    ListView pageList;
    ContactsListAdapter adapter = new ContactsListAdapter();

public ContactsList(final MainActivity activity, RelativeLayout mainXmlLayout ) {   
super(activity);
setLayoutParams( new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));

    addView(mainXmlLayout);

    pageList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactslist);
    pageList.setAdapter(adapter);

    Utils.loadContactsList();
pageList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

activity.registerForContextMenu(pageList);
}//end constructor

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu);

       MenuInflater inflater = MainActivity.getActivity().getMenuInflater();


    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contacts_context_menu, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Contact"); 

    }
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
//....
        return false;
    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adView, View target, int position, long id) {
//.....
}

and in the  activity I have: 

    @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

         Utils.logErrorMessage("info = "+info);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {...}
    }//end method



}
```

Comment: Can you please post more code to see where and how are you using this code?

Comment: I've done that please

Comment: Is an activity where you do AdapterContextMenuInfo info = ... or is a fragment?

Comment: Yes, its in the activity...should it be in the fragment?

Comment: I think that you can't access that from the activity. Try from the fragment. I'm not an expert but maybe that's the point

Comment: I thought about that, let me do it thanks!

Comment: It didn't work, its still null please

Comment: Have you put your onContextItemSelected inside class ContactList? and it doesnt work? If it's not that I don't know what can be sorry

Comment: Its not allowed to put onContextItemSelected in the View class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem by changing the structure of my application a bit. Instead of defining the context menus in the views I set a tag on the ListViews that needed context menus and used a switch statement to define them in the parent activity's onCreateContextMenu. Then I accessed them the normal way in the activity's onContextItemSelected method. e.g.

First, I set the tag on the list in the parent view's class constructor:

e.g.

```
pageList.setTag("Contacts");
```

Then in the activity that contains the view:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

switch (v.getTag().toString()) {
    case "Contacts":
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contacts_context_menu, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Contact");
        break;
    case "Chats":
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_contacts_context_menu, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Contact");
        break;
    case "GroupChats":
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.groups_context_menu, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Your Group");  
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }      
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

         Utils.logErrorMessage("info = "+info);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.chatwithcontact:
    //...do something
     return true;
    }

    }//end method
```